# Trying to get data from event logs into html in email

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get event log entries into html I have had success with other cmdlets been fighting this too long.
here is what I am doing:

```
Get-EventLog -logName EDEN.AppServer -AFTER $lastCheck.Date | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -eq 'Error'}
```

in the console the output looks like I want
[image: consoleOut]

but once I assign it to variable and stick in html I get this.

```psh
$html = @"
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src = "cid:logo.jpg"/>
  <div>
  <P></P>
  <h>Eden Application Server Information</h>
  <p>Computer Name: $($EasHostInfo.Name)</p>
  <p>EAS Version: $($easVersion.Version) </p>
  <p>Eden Version: $($EasEdenVersion.LastVersion)</p>
  <p>EAS Error Log: There was$($EasLog)</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
"@
```

[image: In HTML]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us how you "stick" it in html? :)

Comment: I have tried multiple variations using different properties like $EasLog.Entries,$easLog.Log.ToString() not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: I figured out one way to do this:  $EasLog = Get-EventLog -logName EDEN.AppServer -AFTER $lastCheck.Date | Where-Object {$_.EntryType -eq 'Error'} | ConvertTo-Html

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing us the middle steps as to how you made `$EasEdenVersion` but it does not particularly matter in this case. You are trying to squeeze complex object into a single `<p>`. If I had to guess you are putting in all the `name`s of returned records into one paragraph.

You have objects but you need to create structured html in order to have it displayed properly. `ConvertTo-HTML` in some way should be able to help here. While it can create whole files and support CSS you already have the start of a file so lets see if we can work with that.

```
$html = @"
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src = "cid:logo.jpg"/>
  <div>
  <P></P>
  <h>Eden Application Server Information</h>
  {0}
</div>
</body>
</html>
"@

$table = Get-EventLog -logName Application -AFTER (Get-Date).AddDays(-6) | 
    Where-Object {$_.EntryType -eq 'Error'} | 
    ConvertTo-Html -Fragment | Out-String

$html -f $table
```

Mostly to prove a concept I have edited your `$html` with a placeholder `{0}` for a HTML table. That table comes from the output of `Get-EventLog` which is converted to a HTML table using `-Fragment` and saved as one whole string. That string is then inserted into the `$html` using the format operator.

[image: Sample Output]

You will notice that I have not selected any specific properties and that not all properties were saved as readable strings. You are going to need to use `Select-Object` to get the properties you want like `name`, `version` and `lastversion`.